# Export table data to PDF using SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I have table with data, after exporting data in PDF, which was showing all table data in single column. Here is screen-shot of PDF :  [image: pdf image - All table data coming in single column]

> **Note:** To export in pdf I have used *pdfmake.min.js* & *vfs_fonts.js* library

Now I want, All data should come in four column & two rows with table header, Here is my code

**xml code**

```html
<Table id="placeTbl">
  <columns>
    <Column>
      <Text text="First Name"/>
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Text text="Last Name"/>
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Text text="age"/>
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Text text="Contact"/>
    </Column>
  </columns>
</Table>

<Button text ="Export To PDF" press="downloadpdf"/>
```

**JS code**

```js
downloadpdf : function() {

  var oTable = this.getView().byId("placeTbl");
  var odata = oTable.getItems();

  var docDefinition = {
    pageSize : 'A4',
    pageOrientation : 'portrait',
    content : [ {
      table : {
        // widths: ['*', '*'],
        headerRows : 1,
        widths : [ '*', '*', '*' ],
        body : []
        // ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'age', 'contact']
      }
    } ],
    styles : {
      tableExample : {
        margin : [ 0, 10, 0, 15 ]
      },
    }
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < odata.length; i++) {
    docDefinition.content[0].table.body
    .push([ odata[i].mAggregations.cells[0].mProperties.text ]);
    docDefinition.content[0].table.body
    .push([ odata[i].mAggregations.cells[1].mProperties.text ]);
    docDefinition.content[0].table.body
    .push([ odata[i].mAggregations.cells[2].mProperties.text ]);
    docDefinition.content[0].table.body
    .push([ odata[i].mAggregations.cells[3].mProperties.text ]);

  }
  pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();
}
```

After exporting to pdf, the table structure I want like this in PDF

[image: Example for after exporting pdf should look like this]

Comment: So what is your question? Or is it "can you please do my work for me"?

Comment: I want to show pdf data is in table format i.e. four column as defined in xml, but when exporting the data to pdf then data showing in single column. Is there anything style I am missing..?